# How to retrieve multiple owners of a polymorphic relation in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-associations, laravel-4, eloquent

3 tables listed below:
users

```
id username
```

orders

```
id price
```

history

```
id historable_id historable_type
```

I want to retrieve all the orders with a specific history id in orders view

Orders Model:

```
public function history(){  
    return $this->morphMany('History','historable');}
```

OrderController:

```
public function index(){  
    var_dump(History::find(1)->historable->toArray());}
```

There're more than one order with history id 1, but only the first order is found. How can I get all the others with the same history id?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but do you not want to do History::where('historable_id', '=', '1')->get()? Currently you are retrieving the row in the history table with an ID of 1, rather than all rows that match orders with an ID of 1. find() is looking at the 'id' column on the history table, you want to be looking at the 'historable_id' column.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the discussion in the comments, the solution was to retrieve the records based on the 'historable_id' column, rather than the regular column.

```
History::where('historable_id', '=', '1')->get();
```

Or alternatively:

```
Order::find(1)->history;
```